# Why for..in() loop doesn't return objects inside of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have this piece of code in an angular controller that looks like so:

```
for (var obj in $scope.items) {
   obj.done = false;
}
```

Here's how my `$scope.items` look:

```
$scope.items = [
  {
    name: "Task #1",
    done: false
  },
  {
    name: "Task #2",
    done: false
  }
];
```

It seems weird to me that my for loop actually doesn't work. `obj` isn't an object within the loop. I tried to do a `console.log` of the `obj` variable and it prints out the index of the array `$scope.items`. Why is this so? Since this is a `foreach` loop, shouldn't `obj` be each of the objects inside `$scope.items`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for..in` [enumerates the property *names*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) of an object:

```
var foo = { a: 5, b: 7 };
for (var x in foo) {
    console.log(x);
}
// -> a
// -> b
```

If you want the property *values*, you just look up the property in the object using the name:

```
var foo = { a: 5, b: 7 };
for (var x in foo) {
    var value = foo[x];
    console.log(value);
}
// -> 5
// -> 7
```

For arrays however, it's not a good idea to work with its properties to iterate over its elements. If you add a regular property to an array, such as:

```
var arr = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
arr.myProp = "someValue";
```

then `myProp` will also show up in the `for..in` loop, which is often unwanted. Instead, it is highly recommended to iterate over an array using a *regular* `for` loop or using `Array.forEach`:

```
arr.forEach(function(value, index) {
    console.log(value);
})
// -> 1
// -> 2
// -> 3
```

Answer (score 4):

`for .. in` iterates over keys (or indexes), not values. You should do:

```
for (var index in $scope.items) {
    $scope.items[index].done = false;
}
```

In general, it's considered as [a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) to use `for .. in` to iterate over arrays. You could use `forEach` method instead:

```
$scope.items.forEach(function (item) {
    item.done = false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What `for..in` does is to iterate over attributes or properties of an object, not elements of an array. If you want to iterate over an array, then you should use normal `for` loop `for(var i =0; i<n; i++)..`